# Javascript/Typescript: regex to find something between < > without custom tags

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've to write a regex which matches everything between < and > (I think is something like `'<(.*)>'` ) but which not includes expression like these:

- `<p .... >` (something starting with `<p` and ends with `>`)
- `<b .... >` (something starting with `<b` and ends with `>`)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML with Regex? If so [Just don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Can you please add more examples? Should the regex in this case `<p style="position:absolute">Text</p>` match `p` or `p style="position:absolute"`

Comment: Yes, but it ins't a generic HTML, it will be generated by my custom component so it is a very reductive case. I've the control of tags will be placed there.

Comment: Some cases: ```<div style='test'>``` will match; ```<p style='test'>``` won't match ```p others``` won't match; ```<b>``` won't match

Comment: "I've the control of tags".  Do you have complete control over everything in there?  No user input at all?  No angle brackets in attribute values?  And if you do have complete control, why not figure this out before you create the HTML?  Even if using regex to parse HTML were not dangerous, it's still the wrong tool for the job.  Here's a fork you can stick into the toaster: `/<(?![bp]\W)[^>]*>/`.  Please be careful with it!!